# How to pass data from Model to View Model when using model auto-properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, .net-core

I have a Model class (User) in which I have multiple auto properties which are populated by an API call.

```
public class User
    {
        public string Login { get; set; }

        public long Id { get; set; }
```

...etc

I want to populate a ViewModel so I can bind this data to my WPF Window, but I am struggling to do so. In various examples I have seen they created an onChange method within the Model - however I'm still not sure on how to pass this data to the ViewModel.

In the ViewModel I have seen people implement the interface INotifyPropertyChanged but still unsure how I can map this to the model or a specific property when using auto properties in the model.

Comment: The view model may have a User property (of type User) with INotifyPropertyChanged implementation. Notify the view about model changes by assigning a new User instance to that property.

Comment: Your tags are...odd. WPF/MVVM and ASP.NET use a very different Flavor of Binding. ASP also tends towards the "MVC" pattern. Do not mix those two up. If you really are looking for MVVM/WPF Flavor of binding, I did wrote a intro into that pattern: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf The core trick is to encapsulate the Model classes in your ViewModel ones, and only use the model via the ViewModel.

Comment: The tag was meant to be .NET-Core, that was accidental. Thank you for the resource however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap the data model you get from the API call in a type that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and expose it from your view model. The wrapping type delegates the data to the underlying model:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string Login { get; set; }

    public long Id { get; set; } 
} 

public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public User(UserModel dataModel)
  {
    this.UserModel = dataModel;
  }

  public string Login 
  {
    get => this.UserModel.Login;
    set
    {
      if (Equals(value, this.UserModel.Login)) return;
      this.UserModel.Login = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public string Id 
  {
    get => this.UserModel.Id;
    set
    {
      if (Equals(value, this.UserModel.Id)) return;
      this.UserModel.Id = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private UserModel UserModel { get; set; }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private getUser()
  {
    UserModel = modelData = Api.GetUser();
    this.User = new User(modelData);
  }

  private User user;
  public User User
  {
    get => this.user;
    set
    {
      if (Equals(value, this.user)) return;
      this.user= value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Used MVVMLight  tool for GOLOSOFT 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LaurentBugnion.MVVMLightforVS2017
install
direct used mvvminpc then tab automatically create

ex

```
mvvminpc
```

then press tab

automatic create following code

```
      /// <summary>
        /// The <see cref="MyProperty" /> property's name.
        /// </summary>
    public const string MyPropertyPropertyName = "MyProperty";

    private bool _myProperty = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the MyProperty property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public bool MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _myProperty;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_myProperty == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _myProperty = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(MyPropertyPropertyName);
        }
    }
```

selected MyProperty to chnage name and press tab button